# loading image on chrome mobile

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, nuxt.js

I have a website created by Nuxt js. On the landing page, I have 3 images supposed to show immediately with no transition (all at the same time). The problem is 2 of 3 images didn't show up on the first load and it works normally after I refresh the page, this happens only in chrome normal browser mode, work normally in incognito and also the others browser like Edge. I tried to remove many properties but the ploblem still there. Please suggest me some solutions. Thanks

chrome v.91.0.4472.120

Comment: There is probably some blocker of some sort. Like adblock or an extension. If it is working in incognito, it should work anywhere. Maybe try to access your website on somebody's Chrome, to be sure that this is coming from here.

Comment: Thanks kissu, but this happen to all of my friend they all get the same ploblem only in chrome. BTW I will leave the link here -  www.immbybdms.com

Comment: Which one is not loaded? For me, everything is here as expected. `v91.0.4472.114` here. Can you please show the code for this specific page? Also, what is their resolution? Are you sure their browser is not blocking anything?